# Convert NSString into char array

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

I have a variable of type `char[]` and I want to copy `NSString` value in it. How can I convert an `NSString` to a char array?

Answer (score 107):

Use [`-[NSString UTF8String]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String):

```
NSString *s = @"Some string";
const char *c = [s UTF8String];
```

You could also use [`-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding:) if your string is encoded with something other than UTF-8.

---

Once you have the `const char *`, you can work with it similarly to an array of `chars`:

```
printf("%c\n", c[5]);
```

If you want to modify the string, make a copy:

```
char *cpy = calloc([s length]+1, 1);
strncpy(cpy, c, [s length]);
// Do stuff with cpy
free(cpy);
```

Comment: He asked for a char array this is a const char

Comment: Im looking for a complete answer that shows the code from `NSString *someString` to `char myArray[] =..`. I really need this, could you please update your answer? cheers

Comment: @Maxner: What do you need to do? In most cases, a pointer to chars can be used like a char array.

Comment: I need a char array like this one `char csignid[] = "something";` but with the `something`from an NSString. I need it to be able to modify the array like this `csignid[5] = a+0x21;`. Declaring the char array like this `char csignid[] = [@"dunno" UTF8String];` or `const char* csignid[] = [@"" UTF8String];`returns an error message saying 'Array initializer must be an initializer list'. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest the following one-liner to get a cstring copy strdup([s UTF8String]);

Answer (score 14):

mipadi's answer is the best if you just want a `char*` containing the contents of the string, however NSString provides methods for obtaining the data into a buffer that you have allocated yourself. For example, you can copy the characters into an array of `unichar` using [`getCharacters:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_49) like this:

```
NSUInteger length = [str length];
unichar buffer[length];

[str getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    doSomethingWithThis(buffer[i]);
}
```

If you have to use `char`, then you can use the more complicated [`getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_48) like this (demonstrated in [Eastern Polish Christmas Tree](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/6/1/43942/41236) notation):

```
NSUInteger length = [str length];
NSUInteger bufferSize = 500;

char buffer[bufferSize] = {0};

[str       getBytes:buffer
          maxLength:(bufferSize - 1)
         usedLength:NULL
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            options:0
              range:NSMakeRange(0, length)
     remainingRange:NULL];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `getCharacters:range:`, I use:

```
[stringToCopy getCString:c_buffer maxLength:c_buffer_length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The result is a **char[]** (instead of **unichar[]**), which is what the OP was wanting, and what you probably want to use for C compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, a char array is bridged as an `UnsafePointer<Int8>`.  Accessing characters works the same way in Swift for an `NSString`:

```
let str: NSString = "hello"
let charStr = str.UTF8String // UnsafePointer<Int8>
```

For a Swift `String` object things are a little different:

```
let str = "hello"
let charStr = str.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

`charStr` is `[CChar]?` where `CChar` is a typeailais for `Int8`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to play NSString as a character array for working on coding practices which is otherwise much simpler to do in plain C coding. Using **characterAtIndex:** and  **appendFormat:** helps me. May be this will help.

```
NSString *str = @"abcdef";
NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
  char ch = [str characterAtIndex:i];
  [strResult appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
}
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Comment: whats the diff between your answer and.... NSMutableString *strResult  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str]; ?