# Taking letter from string into an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

Is there any way to split up a NSString to an array with all the letters separated?

Something like:

`NSString *str = @"hey dude";`

`//Array output : h,e,y,d,u,d,e`

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array) out

Answer (score 0):

[stringToCopy getCString:c_buffer maxLength:c_buffer_length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Would this return `h,e,y, ,d,u,d,e` instead? Take note of the white space.