# How to split string into substring?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsstring, substring

I want to split the below string into sub string,
 `string = 000000000000000000111111111111111111111111000000`. How to split like we have 48 characters in the mentioned string? I want to separate each character into an array so that I can fetch the values based on the index.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [convert nsstring into char array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
unichar aCharacter = [string characterAtIndex: charIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve a certain character you can use `[(NSString *)string characterAtIndex:(int)index];`

e.g. get the char at index 0

```
unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:0];
```

[NSString characterAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a)

If you want to split the string into substrings then you can use the split/substring functions `– substringFromIndex:`, `– substringWithRange:` and `– substringToIndex:`. There are lots more methods which you can use as well. Have a look at the [NSString dev reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 0):

By using **toCharArray()** method [See this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

```
String str="000000000000000000111111111111111111111111000000";
char[] cr=str.toCharArray();
System.out.println(cr[18]);//output:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the blow code you can fetch the string with the index

```
NSMutableArray * stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<yourString.length; i++) {
    [stringArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[yourString characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
NSLog(@"string %@",stringArray);
```