# Split NSString in substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to split a string apple into substrings and want to store it in a array where I can get a at array[0] index p at array[1] and so on. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If you just want to access the chars in the string, then characterAtIndex is enough.

Comment: I think he has explained it well..http://stackoverflow.com/a/3581549/1865424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, few of them i am going to mention here:-

1)

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < [yourString length]; i++) {
    [yourArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [yourString characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

2) you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3581549/1865424.

There are other ways too.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *stringBuffer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[string length]];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    [stringBuffer addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]]];
}

// doing stuff with the array
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Convert NSString into char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array)

I don't know if the first of the 4 answers is the most efficient, but it works, is pretty clear in terms of how it's written and unless you've a particularly long string or high frequency of calls, is probably good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const char* x = [String UTF8String];
```

then access characters like x[0] x[1] and so on.