# How to make objective c console line vertical output?

Tags: objective-c, c

Here's my understanding fetching the input:

```
int num = 0;
NSLog (@"Input 5 numbers");

scanf("%d", &num);


NSLog (@"\n You inputted: %d !", num);
```

Sample Input: 54321
Output: 54321

But the output should be:
5
4
3
2
1

Answer (score 0):

I see no one-line-code solution here. It can be achieved with `for` or `while` loop. e.g. you may divide num by 10 or convert it to string and fetch each character.

For an example of converting an NSString to a char array [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array).