# How do I convert NSString to an encoding other than UTF-8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, char, nsstring

I'm working with `c` in iOS Project I'm trying to convert my string to respected type in c , below code is supposed to send to core Library

```
typedef uint16_t    UniCharT;
static const UniCharT s_learnWord[] = {'H', 'e','l','\0'};
```

what i have done till now is `string` is the one what I'm passing

```
NSString * string = @"Hel";
static const UniCharT *a = (UniCharT *)[string UTF8String];
```

But it is failing to convert when more than one character , If i pass one character then working fine please let me where i miss, How can i pass like `s_learnWord ?`

and i tried in `google` and `StackOverFLow` none of the duplicates or answers didn't worked for me like this
[Convert NSString into char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array) I'm already doing same way only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSString into char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581532/convert-nsstring-into-char-array)

Comment: i don't think so roy , i'm doing same conversion any way i updated my question, Thank you

Comment: `UTF8String` returns `const char *`. What is it `UniCharT`?

Comment: that  is typedef `uint16_t `

Comment: and one morething is i have to pass `const UniCharT* insertString;` this is declared in library so i have to pass to `insertString`

Comment: `uint16_t s_learnWord[] = {'H', 'e','l','\0'};` also shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous as the title says "c type char[]" but your code uses `typedef uint16_t UniCharT;` which is contradictory.

For any string conversions other than UTF-8, you normally want to use the method [`getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415702-getcstring?language=objc).

As you are using `uint16_t`, you probably are trying to use UTF-16? You'll want to pass [`NSUTF16StringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1497293-anonymous/nsutf16stringencoding?language=objc) as the encoding constant in that case. (Or possibly `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding`/`NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`)

Something like this should work:

```
include <stdlib.h>

// ...

NSString * string = @"part";
NSUInteger stringBytes = [string maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding];
stringBytes += sizeof(UniCharT); // make space for \0 termination
UniCharT* convertedString = calloc(1, stringBytes);
[string getCString:(char*)convertedString
         maxLength:stringBytes
          encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

// now use convertedString, pass it to library etc.

free(convertedString);
```

Comment: Or `cStringUsingEncoding:`

Comment: @Cy-4AH [The documentation for `cStringUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstringusingencoding?language=objc) states "**Special Considerations**
UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not considered to be C string encodings, and should not be used with this method—the results of passing NSUTF16StringEncoding, NSUTF32StringEncoding, or any of their variants are undefined." So no, don't use  `cStringUsingEncoding:` here.

Comment: i mean okay `static const UniCharT s_learnWord[] = {'H', 'e','l','\0'};` if i pass this it is working fine, can you please suggest me how to convert like `s_learnWord` from `NSString`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've given an example that should help you get started.

Comment: @pmdj Thanks man you are right i need to convert `UTF16String`, working fine now